# how to display label messages in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a button which reads the data in the sheet and display it in Grid View and i have a label which display the messages for those empty fields in the sheet but i need to display those messages in a Grid View how can i do this

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" ShowHeader="False" Height="114px" Width="182px">
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Label ID="UploadStatusLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>

UploadStatusLabel.Text = msg1;
```

This is the label which display the messages and this label is current in insert button where the messages are displayed after inserting in database but these messages should be displayed in gridview how can i do this

Answer (score 0):

You need a RowDataBound event

```
if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0) 
{
    Label LabelYouWant = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("Label_You_Want_To_Access_In_Your_ItemTemplate_Of_GridView");
    if (LabelYouWant != null) 
    {
        LabelYouWant.Text = "Assign What You want!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`OnRowDataBound` you could check for which column its null and append your text there:

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
      if(e.Row.Cells[cellno]=="") 
       {
          e.Row.Cells[cellno].Text = msg1
       }
    }
}
```